# Loop Video background in Beamer

Tags: beamer, backgrounds, multimedia

I want to have a  video background that will loop on some frames of my presentation. Can anyone help me to do that?

Comment: Impossible, as embedded media bubble up to the top when activated in the PDF viewer.

Comment: @AlexG Could you convert your comment into an answer? This way other questions can be marked as duplicate to this one (e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/402887/36296)

Answer (score 1):

*Converting [@AlexG](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366355/loop-video-background-in-beamer#comment903116_366355)'s comment into a CW answer:*

> Impossible, as embedded media bubble up to the top when activated in the PDF viewer.

Comment: Thank you and apologies, simply forgot to fullfil your request.

Comment: @AlexG If you would like to post an answer yourself, I will happily delete this one and upvote yours! (then I could vote as duplicate for the other question :)

Comment: No, not necessary; no need for score hunting. Thank you again!