# Superimpose content to a movie in beamer

Tags: beamer, tikz-pic, multimedia, layers

When using the command `\movie` in beamer, from the package multimedia, it appears that the movie itself appears on top of every other content, so that it seems impossible to display any content over it.

For instance, I've tried to use a `tikzpicture` workaround as shown below. But can't manage to have any content superimposed.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node (movie) at (current page.center) {
\movie[width =\paperwidth, height=0.599\paperwidth, poster, autostart, loop]{}{videoTest.mp4}
};
\node (test) at (current page.center) {
Content that should appear over the movie
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The movie works well, therefore my question focuses on layer management.

Comment: We had this question once before (I cannot find it right now). The answer then was this is not possible due to technical reasons.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366355/loop-video-background-in-beamer

Comment: Ok, what a shame... but the explanation is understandable. Thanks for your responses.